# ¿Como quitar el splash screen de defecto en kotlin android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, programación-móvil, splash

Busque por Youtube y pude hacer mi Splash screen lo que pasa es que al momento de iniciar la app, primero me lanza una pantalla en blanco (supongo que es el Splash screen por defecto de kotlin) y después me carga el Splash screen mío (el que yo cree con el logo y nombre de la app) , y después la aplicación en si.

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de eliminar esa pantalla en blanco, o si saben cómo crear un Splash screen directo, como en instagram o discord, que al presionar la app, me salga el Splash screen que yo he creado y después la app.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] que te brinda información de como realizar preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin no ofrece un Splash screen por defecto, lo que puede estar pasando es que estas creando tu splash screen con una Activity, entonces al momento de iniciar la app se muestra la pantalla en blanco por defecto que permite que la app se cargue.

Si es así, es decir estas usado un activity,y quieres que tu splash screen  aparesca inmediatamente sin mostrar  el fondo blanco deberías crear tu splash screen usando un tema, esta es la mejor forma para crear un splash screen.

Crea un archivo xml en tu carpeta DRAWABLE, este será el fondo que utilizaras como splash screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Luego en tu carpeta VALUES, puedes encontrar un archivo llamado STYLES o otro llamado temas, depende de como hallas creado tu proyecto, posiblemente si has usado una actividad vacía al momento de crearlo tengas el archivo "STYLES".
Al abrirlo encontraras, lo siguiente.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Prueba" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        ........
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        .......
    </style>

    AGREGAS LA SIGUIENTE LINEA DESPUES DE LA ETIQUETA "</styles>"
    <style name="splashScreen" parent="Theme.Prueba">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_image</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Esta linea crea un nuevo Tema llamado name = "splashScreen" el cual esta heredando de tu tema principal parent="Theme.Prueba" , por ende el nombre que coloques aqui debe ser el mismo que el de el tema principal, el cual se especifica arriba.
Este tiene un fondo en este caso, el mismo que acabas de crear para tu splash screen "`<item name="android:windowBackground">AQUI VA EL NOMBRE DEL ARCHIVO QUE CREASTE AL INICIO</item>"`

Solo quedaria cargar este tema al iniciar la app, en tu archivo manifiesto agrega la siguiente linea

```
android:theme="@style/splashScreen
```

Deberia verse asi.

```
<application
        .....
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        .......
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreen"    --->AQUI LO AGREGAS
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Ahora en tu actividad principal, tendrás que volver a cargar tu tema normal, después de que la app muestre el splash screen.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Victory)   //AGREGAS LA SIGUIENTE LINEA ANTES DE  LA DE ABAJO
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Asi debe estar tu MainActivity,  recuerda que `setTheme(RUTA A TU THEMA PRINCIPAL, ES DECIR EL TEMA PADRE),

De esa forma ya no tendrás esa pantalla en blaco al abrir tu app, ahora se mostrara inmediatamente tu splash screen.

Espero que esto haya sido a lo que te referías, recuerda que debes proporcionar la información suficiente para que puedas recibir ayuda, podrías haber creado tu splash screen de muchas formas, entonces como saber cual es tu problemas.

Si tienes mas dudas me encantaría ayudarte en lo que pueda!